# Meaning of log-fit_ratio lnω in rstanarm AOV output

Tags: r, interpretation, stan

In the output of rstanarm's `stan_aov()` one of the parameters is the so-called `log-fit_ratio`, which, in one of [the vignettes](https://mc-stan.org/rstanarm/articles/lm.html#example), is described as ln($\omega$).

How is this parameter to be read and interpreted, and how is it calculated? I couldn't find anything in the vignettes nor in rstanarm's documentation.

Answer (score 2):

$\omega$ is proportional to the marginal standard deviation of the outcome, and `log_fit_ratio` is its logarithm. The latter is a primitive parameter, so rstanarm is drawing from its posterior distribution along with all the other parameters.

If the `log_fit_ratio` is close to zero, which it typically is, then the marginal standard deviation of the posterior predictive distribution of the observed data will tend to be similar to the marginal standard deviation of the observed data. But it is not particularly meaningful in an anova context.